# Canada visa - LA Passport submission process after Nov 1, 2018

Tags: visas, air-travel, canada, embassies

Seems like the VAC in Los Angeles has moved to

Canadian Visa Application Centre – Los Angeles
8530 Wilshire Street, Suite 450
Beverly Hills, CA, 90211
U.S.A.

https://www.vfsglobal.ca/Canada/USA/how_to_apply.html says that the passport must be submitted to the above address along with the request letter. Also, the service fee will be payable to TT Services (https://www.vfsglobal.ca/Canada/USA/Service_and_Service_Charge.html). The service fee seems to be $19.90 USD

So, 
The old process was to mail two packages

- First with VAC service charge of 32.27 payable to CSRA Consular Services
- Second with passport, passport request form and other documentation

The new process is to mail a single package

- With VAC service charge of $19.90 payable to TT Visa Services Inc., passport, passport request form and other documentation.

Is that correct? I should not be mailing a money order to CSRA anymore, right? Please help. The link http://www.csc-cvac.com/en-US/selfservice/cvac_application_processing doesn't have all the information anymore.

Comment: +1 and I wish you luck. Canada's visa application process was the most confusing I've ever seen _before_ this change. Now it's just worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps others in my boat. I just completed the process.
You need to send

- Passport
- Letter requesting for it
- TT Services Consent Form
- Contact Information
- Payment for Package Transmission
- Prepaid return envelope

Payment needs to be a cashiers cheque or money order in favor of TT Visa Services Inc. Amount 19.90 USD. The new consent form is available here: https://www.vfsglobal.ca/canada/usa/pdf/USA.doc.pdf

All this needs to be sent to Canadian Visa Application Centre – Los Angeles 8530 Wilshire Street, Suite 450 Beverly Hills, CA, 90211 U.S.A.

Comment: If 4 people are applying for tourist visa (2 adults, 2 children) do every member of the party need to sign the TT Services consent form? does everyone need to pay the package transmission fee?